# Why does an install batch not know that i have .net 4.7.1 installed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch

So I am installing cosmos for vs2017 and when I run the .bat file it says I don't have .NET Framework 4.7.1 installed but when I installed it, it said the same thing. So I went to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework and I deleted the other folders (out of date versions) so now all I have in there is v4.7.1 and it still does not know I have it installed... would anyone know why this is? also i am on windows 10... not sure if that will help or not...

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have installed?  .Net Framework 4.7.1 is built-into Windows 10 1709.  It’s not possible for it not to be installed.  So the problem must be the .bat script.  You will have to debug it.

Comment: I am not too sure but I will check when I get home but I assume it is close to there because it was updating everytime I reset it (though it could have been because I updated the system files). And how would I debug a .bat file? also I remember checking files before I went to bed and 4.5 was in .NETCore... Would that be the problem if so where would I download the core?

Comment: First you do understand that `.NET Core` != `.NET Framework`. Second 4.5 is replaced by 4.7 it is not possible for it to have been installed on Windows 10 at any point since 4.6 and now 4.7 was built into Windows 10.

Comment: I don't really have windows 10 my computer only went up to 7 but I installed 10 with a usb... And I know .NET Core is not the same as Framework I just thought the core would assist the framework...

Comment: You said you were using Windows 10, " also i am on windows 10", if you are not using Windows 10 then **edit** your question.  "I just thought the core would assist the framework" - .NET Core and .NET Framework are separate products they can also co-exist on the system.  If you would indicate what version of Windows you are actually using, that would help us, determine what version of the .NET Framework is built-in.  Add/Remove Programs would indicate what versions of the .NET Framework are installed.  Please update your question.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and when I said "I don't really have windows 10 my computer only went up to 7 but I installed 10 with a usb." I said that because my laptop itself had windows 7 but I used a usb and updated it. I have added that because I was not sure if me updating my computer from 7 to 10 would have messed it up or not...

Comment: And when you said "So the problem must be the .bat script. You will have to debug it." How would I debug the .bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework` are the reference assemblies for compiling programs against the .net version. Those only provide the provided functions, but no implementation.

To check the .net version, [you need to view the registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#net_b), go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full` and check the DWORD `Release`

[image]

My Value is `461310` in Windows 8.1, so I have .net framework 4.7.1 installed. If you use Windows 10 v1709, the value is `461308`

Comment: I will check the registry when I get home

Comment: My Release is 461308 exactly what you said it should be

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the .NET issue... All I had to do was delete the part of the script that checked for it

Comment: submit the issue to the developers, so that they can fix it.